# Heisenberg's Uncertainty Forms

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Can Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle be rewritten in terms of energy density

writing
$$\Delta E \Delta T \geqslant  \hbar/2$$
in factors of energy density 
$\Delta \sigma \text{  }= \frac{3\Delta E}{4\pi  r^3}$

I get 
$$\Delta \sigma  \frac{3\text{$\Delta $T}}{4\pi  r^3} \geqslant  \hbar/2$$

does $$\frac{3\text{$\Delta $T}}{4\pi  r^3}$$
represent something?

Or does it make more sense to write
$$\text{$\Delta $x} \frac{\text{$\Delta $E}}{c^2} \geqslant  \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

EDIT after noting Willie's comment I've corrected the form to $\frac{\hbar}{2}$

However, now I see c is constant and can be moved to the right side  - is it mathematical correct to write
$$\text{$\Delta $x} \text{$\Delta $E} \geqslant  \frac{\hbar  c^2}{2}$$
or does this violate the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality? This is the question I was trying to understand at the beginning.

Comment: Your algebra's not right. The correct expression should be $\frac{4}3 \pi r^3 \Delta\sigma\Delta T \geq h/2$.

Comment: Really? Ok - but I was using Kennard's "Zur Quantenmechanik einfacher Bewegungstypen" where planck's unit is modified by h/4Pi. Sorry, wenn mein Englisch ist neunzehnten Jahrhunderts

Comment: ""Sorry, wenn mein Englisch ist neunzehnten Jahrhunderts "" So, congratulation to more than 111 years of age! :=)

Comment: Please fix the question! The factor of c should not be squared, it should be $\Delta X \Delta E \approx \hbar c$, the density form is also wrong, as Willy Wong said.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing what $\Delta T$  is here. It is not an interval of time. It is time uncertainty. Which is not what usually called $\Delta T$. The most standard application for this uncertainty principle is a linewidth. From this inequality you know that lifetime in upper state limits lower bound of energy dispersion. The larger lifetime the more precise your energy measurement (may be).

As a consequence, there is no use to convert this $\Delta T$ to $\Delta x$. It will mean not what you expect.

The same holds for $\Delta E$. It is not a real energy of some object.